# undefined variable in typescript?

Tags: javascript, ionic3, w3c-geolocation

I am working on an app that display user's position info (latitude,...) with ionic 3 to do that am using the geolocation plugin but I keep getting undefined variable here's my code.

```
posit(){
    this.geolocation.watchPosition({enableHighAccuracy:true}).subscribe((data)=>{
        this.latitude=data.coords.latitude;
        this.longitude=data.coords.longitude;
        this.altitude= data.coords.altitude;
        console.log("geolocalisation");
        this.prec=data.coords.accuracy;
        this.speed=data.coords.speed;
        this.timestamp=this.time_stamp(data.timestamp);
        this.testvar=[data.coords.latitude,data.coords.longitude];
        console.log(this.prec)//i get the true value 
    });
    console.log(this.prec)//i get undefined
    return this.testvar;
}
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You're just trying to use it before it has a value; the callback is **asynchronous**, it happens later, after `posit` has returned. See the linked question's answers for details.

Comment: I did i get 1120

Comment: You are binding value to this.prec after promise resolve. That's why you are getting value inside subscribe. You need to return value from inside subscribe. Take a look at callback function / promise / async await